# Magento1.9 : How to implement pwa manifest and serviceworker in theme head.pttml

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-theme, pwa

I have created a custom magento theme, not integrated any magento function yet, only created phtml files with static data now.

I'm thinking to create `PWA` for this to get data via `API/ajax` (when network available) and from `cache` (offline mode).

But I'm trying to add `manifest.json` in `head.phtml` file, but it is showing 404 not found error, while it is exist in same folder. like :

```
<link rel="manifest" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN); ?>frontend/default/custom_theme/manifest.json">
```

Am I going to right way or not?, How should I add `manifest.json` in `head.phtml` file?